# Plot values of two time series with different dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, interpolation, resampling

I have two time series. Each time series (s1 and s2) is represented by a list of values and a corresponding list of times (for example timestamps or whatever). I am using python, so for example I have:

```
s1_values = [6,8,6,3,7,9] # len(s1_values) == len(s1_times)
s1_times =  [1,3,6,7,8,12]

s2_values = [3,8,7,2,5,4,6,2] # len(s2_values) == len(s2_times)
s2_times =  [2,4,5,7,8,9,10,13]
```

I would like to see the relation between the two time series s1 and s2, so I would like to be able to plot s1_values (on an x axis) against s2_values (on an y axis) using Matplotlib, but since the two time series are not aligned in time, I don't know how to do that.

Maybe there are some common ways of doing this for time series but I am not aware of them.

Comment: What are you trying to plot them in?

Comment: @JamieBull In Matplotlib. By I would like to have a sort of agregated time series s which is a combination of s1 and s2.

Comment: Have you done plotting (t1,s1) and then (t2,s2) on the same plot? If not, go ahead and do it first. That will give you some idea what to do next.

Comment: @Hun I did, but this is not what I asked for.

Comment: What you are talking about is a scatter plot. But the size should match. Seeing a plot that I mentioned earlier can give you some clue how you want to match the size of two time series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pandas` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/)) which is great for time series data. In this case you'd make two dataframes, then merge and sort them.

The `merge` gives you a merged "Time" series (lots on different ways of merging [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/merging.html)), inserting `nan` values into the value columns where there isn't a value for that time. This is then sorted by the shared `Time` column. The `df.fillna` function ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)) accepts the `method` parameter which if it is `ffill` or `pad` fills gaps with the last valid value, and if `bfill` fills with the next valid value. Alternatively you can use `df.interpolate` for linear interpolation of missing values ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)).

The handy thing is `pandas` wraps `matplotlib` so you can just plot directly from the dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


s1_values = [6,8,6,3,7,9] 
s1_times =  [1,3,6,7,8,12]

s2_values = [3,8,7,2,5,4,6,2]
s2_times =  [2,4,5,7,8,9,10,13]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(s1_times, s1_values), columns=['Time', 's1 values'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip(s2_times, s2_values), columns=['Time', 's2 values'])

df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='Time', sort='Time')
df.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)  # or df.interpolate(inplace=True)

df.plot(kind='scatter', x='s1 values', y='s2 values')
plt.show()
```

Using `fillna(method='ffill')`

[image]

Using `interpolate()`

[image]

Comment: Yes, that would work. You will only need to sort by the Time column once before you interpolate or fill though.